# How do I trigger sound alert in OSX using Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

When Finder finishes copying of files then it triggers a sound alert. How can I do that from my app?

Please note that it is not the same as simply playing a sound. I am from Windows background so I am assuming that OSX allows users to configure notification sound from some central location. So, if the user chooses a different sound for an event then that API should play that new sound. This way I can make my app gel into the system and it will be able to alert the user using sound which the user is familiar with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question.

- Found a good guide on this - [System Sounds in Cocoa (wayback machine archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20111213204051/http://www.shawnmiranda.com/Programming/Blog/2009/10/23/system-sounds-in-cocoa/).
- Official guide - [Introduction to Sound Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sound/Sound.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000104-SW1).
- Official [NSSound reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Update**

***Additional notes***

The system alerts are the ones which user can configure, others like emptying recycle bin, sound made when copying files are not.

`NSBeep` is the simplest way to trigger the alert sound which notifies the user of an error. Other sounds are available at the following locations in Lion.

- `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds`
- For other user interface sounds check the `Resources` folder under related packages of the core applications. These application packages can be found in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`.

So, for example if you want to play the move to recycle bin sound then use the following code.

```
NSSound *systemSound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/dock/drag to trash.aif" byReference:YES];
if (systemSound) {
    [systemSound play];
}
```

***Caveats***

The name and path of the sound files may change at anytime. In fact the location of `SystemSounds` before Lion was `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds`.

Answer (score 4):

You should also check this guide http://cocoathings.blogspot.com/2013/01/playing-system-sounds.html

Answer (score 2):

```
NSSound(named: "Funk")?.play()
```